# Providing object to any Tiles layout containing Tile in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I have a tile which lists articles from object provided to it. This tile is part of most pages, but not all of them. Is there any way of automatically providing object only to pages which need it (contain specific tile)? Now i just have @ModelAttribute in every controller which points to page containing tile, but that is not very flexible because if you change layout, you also need to change controller.

Comment: Anyway you are using seperate controller for each page and that will return a tile name.so what the use of seperate objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any rule, that one can decide for the request url if the article list is needed, then you can implement a [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html).

That intercept all requests in the `postHandle` method , and add the article list, if the "rule" said that it should be added.